# TensorflowOnSaprk application stuck with fit_generator() followed by predict_generator()

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, keras, data-ingestion

I have a simple pyspark application to run on TensorFlowOnSpark.

I use `TFCluster.InputMode.SPARK` mode to feed RDDs to the model. The fit_generator() method works fine, but the inference phase does not make any progress and stuck. For producibility, I use the diabetes dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database). I split dataset to two parts and placed one part in `trainFolder` and the other part in `testFolder`. The generator method `generate_rdd_data()` feeds batches of data to the model for training and `generate_rdd_test()` does the same for inferencing except it does not yield labels.

Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from tensorflowonspark import TFCluster, TFNode

def main_fun(args, ctx):
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    import numpy

    def generate_rdd_data(tf_feed, batch_size=1):
        print("generate_rdd_data invoked")
        while not tf_feed.should_stop():
            batch = tf_feed.next_batch(batch_size)
            if len(batch)> 0:
                features = []
                lbls = []
                for item in batch:
                    features.append(item[0])
                    lbls.append(item[1])
                xs = numpy.array(features).astype('float32')
                ys = numpy.array(lbls).astype('float32')
                yield (xs, ys)

    def generate_rdd_test(tf_feed, batch_size=1):
        print("generate_rdd_test invoked")
        while not tf_feed.should_stop():
            batch = tf_feed.next_batch(batch_size)
            print("batch len: %s" %len(batch))
            if len(batch)> 0:
                features = []

                for item in batch:
                    features.append(item[0])

                xs = numpy.array(features).astype('float32')

                yield xs

    batch_size = 10
    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    numpy.random.seed(7)
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Fit the model
    tf_feed = TFNode.DataFeed(ctx.mgr)
    model.fit_generator(generator=generate_rdd_data(tf_feed, batch_size),
                        steps_per_epoch=20,
                        epochs=5,
                        verbose=1,
                        callbacks=None)
    tf_feed.terminate()
    # evaluate the model
    tf_feed_eval = TFNode.DataFeed(ctx.mgr, train_mode=False)
    predicts = model.predict_generator(generator=generate_rdd_test(tf_feed_eval, batch_size),
                                      steps=20
                                      )
    tf_feed_eval.batch_results(predicts)
    #tf_feed_eval.terminate()

sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf().setAppName("keras model test on spark (MM)"))
num_executors = 1
num_ps = 0
tensorboard = False
args = None

trainFolder = "/path/to/train"
testFolder = "/path/to/test"

def parse(ln):
    vals = ln.split(',')
    return [float(x) for x in vals[:-1]], int(vals[-1])

def parse_test(ln):
    vals = ln.split(',')
    return [float(x) for x in vals[:-1]]


cluster = TFCluster.run(sc, main_fun, args, num_executors, num_ps, tensorboard, TFCluster.InputMode.SPARK)

dataRDD = sc.textFile(trainFolder).map(parse)
cluster.train(dataRDD, 5)

testRDD = sc.textFile(testFolder).map(parse_test)
predictRDD = cluster.inference(testRDD)
predictRDD.take(2)

cluster.shutdown()

print ('Done!')
```

I submit the job to a standalone cluster on my machine with one executer. Here is the submit script:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit \
--master ${MASTER} \
--conf spark.cores.max=1 \
--conf spark.task.cpus=1 \
--conf spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME" \
/path/to/this_code.py
```

What is missed or maybe is wrong in this example to proceed with the predictions?

Here is the tail of the log from the executer:

```
.
.
.
1/20 [>.............................] - ETA: 18s - loss: 1.4276 - acc: 0.7000
13/20 [==================>...........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.4257 - acc: 0.5000 
20/20 [==============================] - 1s 54ms/step - loss: 1.4379 - acc: 0.4750
2018-08-16 13:50:19,548 INFO (MainThread-50639) Processed 200 items in partition
2018-08-16 13:50:19,578 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='running'
2018-08-16 13:50:19,584 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='running'
2018-08-16 13:50:19,584 INFO (MainThread-50639) Feeding partition <itertools.chain object at 0x10c00b590> into input queue <multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue object at 0xb1f231e50>
2018-08-16 13:50:19,588 INFO (MainThread-50638) terminate() invoked
2018-08-16 13:50:20,616 INFO (MainThread-50639) Processed 200 items in partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,621 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,622 INFO (MainThread-50639) connected to server at ('10.5.193.158', 60356)
2018-08-16 13:50:20,646 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,653 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,653 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,654 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,656 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,689 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,695 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,695 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,696 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,699 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,734 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,740 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,740 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,741 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,744 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,778 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,785 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,785 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,786 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,789 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,822 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,830 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,830 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,831 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,834 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,867 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,874 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,874 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,875 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,878 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,912 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,921 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,922 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,923 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,927 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:20,960 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,966 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:20,966 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,967 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:20,970 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:21,005 INFO (MainThread-50639) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:21,012 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr.state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:21,012 INFO (MainThread-50639) mgr is terminating, skipping partition
2018-08-16 13:50:21,013 INFO (MainThread-50639) Skipped 200 items from partition
2018-08-16 13:50:21,017 INFO (MainThread-50639) TFSparkNode: requesting stop
2018-08-16 13:50:21,163 INFO (MainThread-50618) Connected to TFSparkNode.mgr on 10.5.193.158, executor=0, state='terminating'
2018-08-16 13:50:21,167 INFO (MainThread-50618) Feeding partition <itertools.imap object at 0xb1f231190> into input queue <multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue object at 0xb1f231e50>
2018-08-16 13:50:22,181 INFO (MainThread-50618) Processed 101 items in partition
2018-08-16 13:50:26,188 INFO (MainThread-50638) dropped 292 items from queue
generate_rdd_test invoked
```

Note that the `generate_rdd_test()` method is invoked but nothing happen afterwards. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this response from the TFoS developers team in the [TensorFlowOnSaprk user group mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/tensorflowonspark-users/-XpduK-E78I):

> It looks like you're "terminating" the feed after training and then
>   immediately trying to initiate feeding of the inference data. 
>   Currently, the feeding mechanism ignores all subsequent RDD partitions
>   after the "terminate" invocation...
>
> So, some options:
>    1. Split inferencing into a separate spark-submit application.
>    2. Stop and restart the cluster in the driver.